# Is There a Way to Check Sent Headers with Node/ Express 2.x?

Tags: node.js, header, stream, express

Is there a way of checking what specific headers have been sent using node/ express 2.x?

I have a file download that works perfectly most of the time, but in a few specific instances I get an error in Chrome (no errors in node):

```
Duplicate headers received from server
The response from the server contained duplicate headers. This problem is generally the result of a misconfigured website or proxy. Only the website or proxy administrator can fix this issue.
Error 349 (net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION): Multiple distinct Content-Disposition headers received. This is disallowed to protect against HTTP response splitting attacks.
```

For testing purposes, I'd like to see if a specific header has been sent or not, is there a way of doing this with node.js?

---

...And because someone's going to ask me about the code I use to set headers, I'm piping a stream as the download and are only setting headers in one spot.

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename)
res.setHeader('Content-Length', stats.size)
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf')

stream.pipe(res)
```

Comment: `stream.pipe(res).on('end', function () {console.log(res.headers); });` should log the sent headers, as the response is ended.

Comment: Good idea!  I already have some event handlers for when the stream ends.  After some investigating I found that information is stored in `res._headers`  You should put this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTTP response is a `WritableStream`. When the stream closes, a [finish](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) event is emitted. Thus listening to it does the trick:

```
res.on('finish', function() {
    console.log(res._headers);
});
```

Much more flexible. Can be put in a middleware or a resource handler.

Answer (score 2):

As @generalhenry stated on my question comments:

```
stream.pipe(res).on('end', function () {
  console.log(res._headers); 
});
```

The above line worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
res.set("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+file.name+"\"")
```

This worked for me.